# Best solution for weather data warehouse netcdf or grib

Tags: postgresql, bigdata, data-warehouse, netcdf, grib

*Problem:*

Looking for best solution to store and make easily available big amount of weather data for the machine learning specialists team.
Initially I'm fetching data from cds.climate.copernicus.eu in **netCDF** or **grib** format. There will be some around **10-20Tb** in grib or netCDF.

*Requirements:*

- ML specialists can easily query data for given location (point, polygon) in given time range.
- Results are returned in reasonable time.

*Ideas:*

- **Postgres**. I thought that maybe pg would handle that amount of data. But the problem I encoutered with this is that loading data into postgres will take ages additionally it would take much more space than 10-20Tb (Because I planned to store that in row like format where you have two tables Point and WeatherMeasurement) Is it a good idea? Have anyone experience with this kind of data and pg?
- **Amazon Redshift**. Would it be good approach to use this solution for weather data. How to load netCDf or grib into it? I have zero experience with could solutions like this.
- **Files**. Just store data in the grib or netCDF files. I would write some simplified Python interface to fetch data from those files? But the questions is will the queries be fast enough? Have anyone experience with those?

Comment: I have worked on that issue for a long time and I decided to use different solutions for different problems. Fast access to the data can be managed with PostgreSQL. But it is not a solution for archive hundreds or thousands of forecasts because the data is 20-40% bigger and it takes a lot of time to push the data into psql. For the archive I use netcdf file system with lat/lon batched data. For each batch I am having a cKDTree for spatial operations to improve the access speed.

Answer (score 1):

For data this size that you want to sub-select quickly along multiple dimensions I'd lean toward Redshift.  You will want to pay attention to how you want to query the data and establish the data model to provide the fastest access for the needed subsets.  You may want to get some help setting this up initially as trial-and-error approach will take a while with this data size.  Also Redshift isn't cheap at this scale so ask the budget questions too.  This can be reduced if the database only needs to be up part of the time.

Files isn't a terrible idea as long as you can partition the data such that only a subset of files need to be accessed for any query.  A partitioning strategy based on YEAR, MONTH, LAT-Decade, and LON-Decade might work - you'll need to understand what queries need to be performed and how fast (what's reasonable time?).  This approach will be the least cost.

There is also a combo option - Redshift Spectrum.  Redshift can utilize on database information AND in S3 stored data in the same queries.  Again setting up the Redshift data model and S3 partitioning will be critical but this combo could give you attributes that will be valuable.

For any of these options you will want to convert to a more database friendly format like Parquet (or even CSV).  This conversion process along with how to merge new data will need to be understood.  There are lots of cloud tools to help with this processing.

Given the size of data you are working with I'll stress again that learning as you go will be time consuming.  You will likely want to find experts in the tools you are working with (and at the data sizes you have) to get up quickly.